# How does one, in a nested tree like data-structure, add child-nodes to a parent-node's children-array by a parent-node's id?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, data-structures, iteration

I have a json object:

```
const data = {
  id: 'root',
  name: 'Parent',
  children: [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'Child - 1',
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      name: 'Child - 3',
      children: [
        {
          id: '4',
          name: 'Child - 4',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

And I want to add new children arrays dynamically to any parent element, by id. E.g. I want to find element with id='4' and add children: [{ id:'5', name: 'Child - 4' }]

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Comment: ... which boils it down to a search/find task that most probably is based on recursively "walking" the data structure. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was wondering if there is some simple solution to find element by key value without using recursion something like const obj = lodash.filter(data,{value: '4'})

Comment: w3schools.com is (slowly) getting better, but I still would not use this as a reference for anything -> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com

Comment: @RuslanErmahgerd ... *"I was wondering if there is some simple solution ... something like ... `lodash.filter`..."* ... `filter` iterates an array (hence a flat list) but you are dealing with a recursive data structure; thus one needs a recursive approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already suggested in the comment to the OP's question, one could choose a recursive approach which internally iterates a parent node's `children` array via [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in order to achieve both an early exit (on array iteration) and the indication whether (a) child node(s) could be added (in case the targeted parent node exists) by its boolean return value.

One also has to be aware of possible child node duplicates (via their `id`s) and how to treat them.

```js
// E.g. I want to find element with id='4'
// and add children: [{ id:'5', name: 'Child - 4' }]

const data = {
  id: 'root',
  name: 'Parent',
  children: [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'Child - 1',
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      name: 'Child - 3',
      children: [
        {
          id: '4',
          name: 'Child - 4',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

function addChildrenToParentByParentId(id, node, childNodes) {
  let isSuccess = false;
  
  const { children } = node;
  if (node.id === id) {

    // because `childNodes` can be both a single node or a node list.
    childNodes = [].concat(childNodes);

    // prevent child node duplicates by ...
    node.children =
      ((Array.isArray(children) && children) || []).filter(child =>
      
        // ... skipping older nodes which feature newer ids ...
        childNodes.every(node => node.id !== child.id)

      // ... and always concatenating the most recent child nodes.
      ).concat(childNodes);

    isSuccess = true;

  } else if (Array.isArray(children)) {

    // recursion ... but using `Array.prototype.some`
    // in order to achieve both an early exit and the
    // indication whether children could be added.

    isSuccess = children.some(child =>
      addChildrenToParentByParentId(id, child, childNodes)
    );
  }
  return isSuccess;
}

// fails ... provides a node list
console.log(
  "addChildrenToParentByParentId('2', data, [{ id:'5', name: 'Child - 4' }]) ...",
  addChildrenToParentByParentId('2', data, [{ id:'5', name: 'Child - 4' }])
);
console.log(data);

// succeeds ... provides a single node
console.log(
  "addChildrenToParentByParentId('4', data, { id:'5', name: 'Child - 4' }) ...",
  addChildrenToParentByParentId('4', data, { id:'5', name: 'Child - 4' })
);
console.log(data);

// succeeds ... provides a node list
console.log(
  "addChildrenToParentByParentId('3', data, [{ id:'6', name: 'Child - 4' }, { id:'7', name: 'Child - 4' }]) ...",
  addChildrenToParentByParentId('3', data, [{ id:'6', name: 'Child - 4' }, { id:'7', name: 'Child - 4' }])
);
console.log(data);

// succeeds ... provides a single node ... prevents duplicates
console.log(
  "addChildrenToParentByParentId('3', data, { id:'6', name: 'Child - XX' }) ...",
  addChildrenToParentByParentId('3', data, { id:'6', name: 'Child - XX' })
);
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can build a recursive function to add data to children array when the `id` is matched.

```js
const data = [{ id: 'root', name: 'Parent', children: [ { id: '1', name: 'Child - 1', }, { id: '3', name: 'Child - 3', children: [ { id: '4', name: 'Child - 4', }, ], }, ],}];

const addDataToId=(arr, id, children)=>{
    arr.forEach(i=>{
        if(i.id==id){
           i.children = [...(i.children || []), ...children];
        } else {
            addDataToId(i.children|| [], id, children)
        }
    })
}

addDataToId(data, 4, [{ id:'5', name: 'Child - 4' }]);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Crazy how just wrapping the object in an array can make it so much easier. I'm still skeptical from the performance side of things though. Great answer and should infact be the accepted one!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to write such functions by separating out the tree-traversal from the predicate which tests whether to work on the current node and from the transforming function which updates the node.

Here is a version with an `alterTree` function which does the tree-traversal, accepting a predicate function and a transformation function and returning a function which takes an object (with `.children` arrays keeping a tree structure) and returning an altered version of that object by transforming all nodes that match the predicate by calling the transformation function on them and leaving other nodes intact:

```js
const alterTree = (pred, trans) => (o) =>
  pred (o)
    ? trans (o)
    : {...o, ...(o .children ? {children: o .children .map (alterTree (pred, trans))} : {})}

const addChildren = (targetId, children) =>
  alterTree (
    ({id}) => id === targetId,
    (node) => ({...node, children: [... (node .children || []), ... children]})
  )


const data = {id: 'root', name: 'Parent', children: [{id: '1', name: 'Child - 1', }, {id: '3', name: 'Child - 3', children: [{id: '4', name: 'Child - 4'}]}]};

console .log (addChildren ('4', [{id: '5', name: 'Child - 5'}]) (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We call `alterTree` in our definition of `addChildren`, passing a function which reports whether the `id` matches our target and a second function which adds nodes.

Note that `alterTree` does its work immutably.  But if the functions you pass to it mutate their inputs, there's no guarantee that we won't mutate your original object.  The ones passed by `addChildren`, however don't mutate anything, so this function also does not mutate the original data.  It returns a new copy of the object with the changes applied.

If we wanted, we could take this a step further, and abstract away the use of `"children"` for our descendant node, but that's getting a bit afield.